# 520 `recv() failed` only when running application as www-data

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, www-data

I'm running a nginx proxy server that fronts a SignalR application with thousands of connected WebSocket clients.

To accommodate all of these connections, I have set the following in `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 60000;
events {
        worker_connections 30000;
}
```

If I run my application up using the `myname` user account, everything operates as expected.

When I try to run the application using a systemd service definition with user `www-data`, the application starts fine, however, about 80% of the requests to the server/application now fail with (from nginx `error.log`):

```
nginx recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

Which results in 520 status codes (cloudflare) to the client application.

The other 20% of requests succeed as expected, so I know the application is running properly.

```
[Unit]
Description=MyApp

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/myname/app/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/myname/app/publish/App.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=MyApp
User=www-data
EnvironmentFile=/myapp.env

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I feel like I am hitting some limit that is below what I have specified with `worker_rlimit_nofile 60000`, and it is causing failures (though could be just a red-herring). Checking `ulimit` for both of these users shows that they have the same:

```
# su - myname -c 'ulimit -aH' -s '/bin/bash'
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31823
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31823
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

# su - www-data -c 'ulimit -aH' -s '/bin/bash'
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31823
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31823
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

What could be causing these failures when operating as `www-data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource limits you may have configured for logged in users (e.g. in `limits.conf`) don't apply to services started by systemd. These resource limits need to be [configured in the service unit itself](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Process%20Properties) or by setting system-wide defaults in [systemd-system.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html).

For example:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=1048576
```

Comment: Excellent. That sounds like the problem. Looking at `/etc/systemd/system.conf` I see no system-wide defaults currently set. So what default value would be used for `LimitNOFILE` if not set in the service unit?

Comment: Probably 1024, which has been the default for decades...